# How to grab a plist item based on a conditional statment?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, plist

If I'm grabbing the data in a plist using:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Providers" ofType:@"plist"];
dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in dataArray)
{
    text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"text"];
    checked = [dictionary valueForKey:@"checked"];
    NSLog(@"%@ checked value is: %@", text, checked);
}
```

How might I go about writing a conditional statement that checks to see only if **checked** is set to **YES** and if so output the text value of the providers

Comment: is checked a BOOL or string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `checked` is stored as a `BOOL` wrapped in `NSNumber`<sup>*</sup>, you can use this code:

```
NSNumber *checked = [dictionary valueForKey:@"checked"];
if ([checked boolValue]) {
    ...
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup> You wrap a `BOOL` in `NSNumber` by calling `[NSNumber numberWithBool:myBoolValue]`.

Comment: @hanumanDev so this should work then, and if it does not, you will see a crash with a "does not respond to selector" message. Did you give it a try?

Comment: it seems to be outputting all the items from the plist. this is what I've had: 
        if ([checked boolValue]) {
            NSString *providers = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text ];
            NSLog(@"providers are %@", providers);
            
        NSMutableArray *dataArray2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:providers, nil];
            
          NSLog(@"providersArray are %@", dataArray2);   
        }   
    }

Comment: @hanumanDev This should work. Are you sure that some items are unchecked?